# Remove inline-block space between two wordpress loop elements?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How do i remove the inline-block space between two divs that are a part of the wordpress loop? They are supposed to sit side-by-side, each being 50% width. I realize I could change the width to 49% or use floats, but I would like to leave it this way if possible.

I know you normally can do it by eliminating the white space in the coding with comments as below:

```
<div class="before-after">
  <img src="images/ba_01.jpg" alt="">
  <h4>Frick TDSH 355XL<br><small>Slide Valve and Rotor Housing</small></h4>
</div><!-- this comment here eleminates the spacing 
--><div class="before-after">
  <img src="images/ba_02.jpg" alt="">
  <h4>Frick NGC300 Gear Plate</h4>
</div>
```

This is my wordpress loop, and no matter where I put the comment, and still adds white space in the actual returned html.

```
<?php 
  $my_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 
      'cat' => '2',             
    ) 
  );

  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
?>  
<div class="before-after">
  <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
      the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
  ?>
  <h4><?php the_title(); ?><br><small><?php the_content(); ?></small></h4>
</div><!-- --><?php endwhile;?><?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

And this is what is showing up in Developer Tools:

```
<div class="before-after">...</div>
<!---->
<div class="before-after">...</div>
<!---->
```

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something easy, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

@Prusprus here it is straight from the source code:

```
<div class="before-after">
    <img width="500" height="300" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ba_02.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Frick NGC300 Gear Plate" />
    <h4>Frick NGC300 Gear Plate<br><small></small></h4>
</div>
<!---->
<div class="before-after">
    <img width="500" height="300" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ba_01.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Frick TDSH 355XL" />
    <h4>Frick TDSH 355XL<br><small><p>Slide Valve and Rotor Housing</p>
    </small></h4>
</div>
<!---->
```

Comment: Can you paste what's returned directly from the source code? I think the developer tools might reformat the code liens for better reading.

Comment: You have a line break between your closing PHP tag and your <div class="before-after"> tag (lines 9 and 10 in your example code). Have you tried close this up?

Comment: That was it! I was so worried about the end of the loop I didn't even think of that. Not sure I would have put two-and-two together anyways. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a different way to mark this as answered, not sure, but @Prusprus gave me the solution in a comment above.

I simply had to remove a line break at the start of my code between the closing php tag and the start of my div.

Comment: I was about to recommend putting all the php in question on one line, then systematically break the code for readability, checking each time to isolate the issue.

Comment: That's exactly where I'll start next time. Thanks!

Comment: Users  should probably upvote the comment as well, to give the real answer more weight. Also, the answer could be deleted and reposted by @Prusprus.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of floating inline-block elements could correct this, but since its unfavored there is another way.

You can also set the letter spacing of the parent element to -0.31em to solve this and set the letter-spacing back to normal in the divs themselves. I'll set up a jsfiddle in a sec.

CODE

```
.row {
     letter-spacing:-0.31em;
}
.col {
     letter-spacing:normal;
     display:inline-block;
     width:50%;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: A suggestion above fixed it, but I appreciate the help! Your way works, but I had to add a container div around my divs to change the letter-spacing, and in this case I just don't want the extra markup. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Two methods here

1. Set the parent's font-size to 0 and then restore it on the `inline-block` elements.
2. Apply a suitable margin to the last div.

[**DEMO x 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/W48RL/)

HTML

```
<div class="opt1">
    <div class="before-after"></div>
    <div class="before-after"></div>
</div>

<div class="opt2">
    <div class="before-after"></div>
    <div class="before-after"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.opt1, .opt2 {    
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.before-after {
    display:inline-block;
    background:lightgrey;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    font-size:16px
    font-size:1rem;
}

.opt1 {
     font-size:0;
}

.opt2 .before-after{
    vertical-align:top;
}

.opt2 .before-after:last-child {
    margin-left:-.25em;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance! Both of these methods work great, but in this specific instance I wanted to do it without adding any extra container divs. I will definitely keep this solutions for the future though. Thanks again!